# MVC 6 API Error "webroot points to a file that does not exist"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting the following error message when I try to run my code. It works fine in my home PC but when I run the code in my work PC I get the following error.

"The 'webroot' property value 'wwwroot' in the project.json file points to a folder that does not exists.

I already delete the .k folder under the user folder.

[image]

this is the project json file

```
{
/* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Factories": "",
    "Infrastructure": ""
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { }
},
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
],
"bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when I cloned one of my repositories to a new PC. In my case, I didn't have anything under wwwroot that was checked into source control, so the cloned copy didn't create the wwwroot folder on the new PC, hence the error.

Create a wwwroot folder and if you have other people cloning your repository, consider checking in a dummy file under wwwroot so that the next person who clones it doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: **Update 4/8/2015** The ASPNET team is now tracking this issue at  https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/233.  Maybe they will fix it in a future release.